# Laravel - can you set multiple parameters in URI for api routes and have additional method name in the controller?

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I tried these in my routes/api.php but it always returned "Target class [API\ProductController] does not exist." even I did migrate:fresh, route:clear, config:clear, cache:clear. Also composer dump-autoload.

I also added the path or namespace in front of the controller but just the same.

I'm using laravel 8. Any idea why?

```
Route::apiResource('/product/order/{item_code}/{coupon_code}', 'App\Http\Controllers\API\ProductController@order'); // item_code/coupon is alpha

Route::get('/product/order/{item_code}/{coupon_code}', 'API\ProductController@order');
```

Comment: What is the full namespace of your ProductController?

Comment: namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

Comment: I've found it easier to use the array-style instead of string style. `Route::apiResource('/product/order/{item_code}/{coupon_code}',[App\Http\Controllers\API\ProductController::class, 'order']);`. However, you cannot have two routes with the exact same route.

Comment: It didn't work for me. If i replace your apiResource to get the it works.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got it fixed now. If I put my order route before the index one then it will be fine. So my routes should be like this. Before I had it reversed and it caused conflict I guess.

```
Route::get('/product/order/{item_code}/{coupon_code}', [ProductController::class, 'order']);

Route::apiResource('/product', ProductController::class);
```